# Is Sentinel-2's JPEG2000 data using signed 15bit or unsigned 15bit pixels?

Tags: landsat-8, sentinel-2, jpeg-2000, bit-depth

I have been working with Sentinel-2 JPEG2000 data and need to extract individual pixels for processing. One issue I have not been able to find an answer to is how the pixels are stored. I was able to determine via ImageMagick's identify command that it is 15-bit.

```
$ identify testfile.jp2
> testfile.jp2 JP2 10980x10980 10980x10980+0+0 15-bit Grayscale Gray 84.46MB 0.010u 0:00.019
```

But I can't seem to find whether it is signed or unsigned. I assume it is unsigned. But want to be sure before I start to deal with larger files.

Also as a bonus question, isn't 15 bit grayscale an unusual format? Normally it is 16 bit, and e.g. Landsat 8 uses unsigned 16-bit GeoTiff and clearly states this.

EDIT: [Seems like a good answer is found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213786/is-sentinel-2s-jpeg2000-data-using-signed-15bit-or-unsigned-15bit-pixels)

Comment: Which GIS system are you using? In ArcMap this is a trivial question, you simply look at the properties of the dataset!

Comment: Well, for my specific purpose I am using python to look at individual pixel values, but I have and can use QGIS. I am using 1C products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I have some more looking into it. And I am now quite certain that ImageMagick is simply wrong. Because the data is not 15 bit, but unsigned 16 bit integers (Uint16). This information is confirmed by QGIS, and ESA's own SNAP software (shown below).

I have not been able to find this in any ESA Copernicus documentation though, which is disappointing. However, it is clearly stated that the sensor is 12 bit, but during processing somewhere to level 1B or 1C this is saved as Uint16.

I am still trying to determine the supposed max value, which for Uint16 is 65535 (2^16 - 1) but the ESA documentation mentioned a max "quantification" spread/value of 10000 for a reflectance of 1 (Refflectance TOA = DN / 10000), where DN = digital number, value of a given pixel. However, I have consistently come across values above 10000. So I am not sure about this yet.

EDIT 2: In certain cases reflectances **can** be greater than 1 (DN > 10000). It seems the DN values are affected by the library and version used to open/decompress JPEG2000, and the way statistics are calculated (e.g. QGIS pixel values are initially quickly estimated; use caution).

EDIT 1: Found a link discussing the issue, doesn't seem like like there is a definitive solution yet. http://forum.step.esa.int/t/the-quantification-value-has-a-true-value-dn-to-toa-reflectance/1220/

[image: Data information from SNAP]

Answer (score 1):

The radiometric resolution (bit depth) of the Sentinel 2 sensor is unsigned 12-bit (0-4095). What processing level are you using? The 2A product should be floating point Bottom-Of-Atmosphere (BOA) corrected reflectance. At minimum you should be accessing 1C processing which is where, in the processing stream, ESA creates the JPEG2000 product. This should still be 12-bit data so, I believe that ImageMagick is not identifying the correct bit depth.

Comment: Yes, I am using 1C data

Comment: I will take another thorough look at it again, values do seem to be between 0-4095, and 12-bit sounds more logical.